# django ManyToMany Image field with different default images

Tags: python, django, model

I have a few models with the Image attribute. I recently got the need to apply many images to an attribute, so i decided to make my own model that includes the image field and relate to it via ManyToMany\OneToMany\OneToOne relationship.

Some of my usecases are:

profile should have only one user-image

post should have OneToMany image field

I created the following Image model:

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image


class PandaImage(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_image_path = kwargs.get('image_path', 'appicon.png')
        self.image = models.ImageField(default=default_image_path, upload_to='profile_pics')

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

        super(PandaImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My question is how can I pass different params\default images from each model to the image model?

for example, I would like the default picture for the profile to be different than the default picture for a post. later, I might want to change the size that I allow for profile pic but not for a post, and so on...

I tried adding a path param to an **init** method in the Image model but I didnt find a way to pass that param to that class when assigning it to an attribut.

eg:

```
image = models.OneToOneField(MyImage, related_name='image', some_default_init_param='default.pnd')
```

gives me on error and didnt pass that kwarg to the MyImage model.

Whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you indicate the error it produces?

Comment: simply that `some_default_init_param` is not a valid argument, which probably makes sense

Comment: Have you tried checking the relationship type in the `save()` method. That is: checking `if self.post` <-checking if it is a post (since it is a 1to1) then check image properties?

Comment: this doesnt sound like an elegant solution because then all the if statements are in the Image model and if you look at the Profile model for example, you cant tell what the default image is which isnt very readable or scalable